# Angular ng-click won't fire if angular {{model}} is included as parameter

Tags: angularjs, click, repeat

I would think this is fairly straight forward, but if I try to include a bound {{data}} model as a parameter in ng-click, nothing happens (an no error is fired in Console).

For example, I have the following:

```
<p ng-repeat='item in array'>
  <a ng-click='function({{item}})'></a>
</p>
```

Here is a plunker that is more fleshed out: [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/7eBNTHGsqva9jz010Grn?p=preview)

If I click on the link, nothing happens.  Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found my own answer:

within ng-click, there is no need for the {{notation}}.  It knows that "item" is an angular data model.  Again, not super clear in the Angular documentation.

Here is the updated [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/7eBNTHGsqva9jz010Grn?p=preview) that shows it working and not working.